# Import to script.js from outside public folder

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, import, node-modules

I want to import a variable from my nodejs index.js file, which is in the root directory, into my script.js file, which is in the public folder (from what I understand, the nodejs index file shouldn't be in the public folder). The index.js file is as so:

```js
const { readFile, readFileSync } = require("fs");
const express = require("express");

const app = express();
app.use(express.static("public"));

const txt = readFileSync("./public/articles/1/title.txt", "utf-8");


app.get("/", (request, response) => {
    readFile("./public/html/index.html", "utf-8", (err, html) => {response.send(html);});
});


app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => console.log(`Live at http://localhost:3000`))

module.exports = { txt };
```

And I then want to import the `txt` variable into my `script.js` file located in `./public/js/script.js`:

```js
import txt from "../index.js";
console.log(txt);
```

However, it still tries to get it from `public/index.js`, at which point it throws a 404 (I'm new to nodejs). Any way to get the variable from `index.js`, or should I move it into the `public` folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were correct not to put `index.js` in your `/public` directory.

For this solution you will need to install a package called [ejs](https://ejs.co/)

```
npm install ejs
```

After installing create a directory called `/views` and move your `public/html/index.html` inside it, and rename it to `index.ejs` (Don't worry you don't need to move your javascript files)

Also modify your main server file `index.js` to this

```
const { readFile, readFileSync } = require("fs");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static("public"));


app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    const txt = readFileSync("./public/articles/1/title.txt", "utf-8");

    res.render("index", { txt }) // render the main file
});


app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => console.log(`Live at http://localhost:3000`))
```

You can read more [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-ejs-in-javascript/) on how ejs works.

Afterwards open your `index.ejs` file and find the line where you import the `script.js` file and modify it to this.

```
<script src="script.js" data-text="<%= txt %>"></script>
```

The `data-text` will provide the Javascript file whatever was inside your `title.txt` file. If you need the text file data displayed inside the page you could just add `<%= txt %>` anywhere inside the `.ejs` file.

Lastly to read the `data-text` value you need to add these lines inside your `script.js`

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var scriptElements = document.querySelectorAll('script[data-text]');
    var txt = scriptElements[scriptElements.length - 1].getAttribute('data-text');

    console.log(txt);
});
```

---

If this solved your problem check this answer as correct!